# Fill columns in pandas´ Data Frame with data from another column inplace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm, out-of-memory

So I´m downloading a lot of data from a SQL database and write those into a Data Frame in PyCharm. Based on the data in one column, I need to create more columns and add them to the Data Frame. While doing this, I´m getting a Memory Error "Can´t allocate array with shape (x, 91000) and dtype int32" - x is always something between 200 and 400. I searched for the Memory Error and already changed the "vm options" so PyCharm has more memory available - I still get the Memory Error.

So I think I need to change my code. I´m creating the new columns by following code:

```
list = pd.unique(df['name'])
list.sort()

for idx in list:
    col1 = '%s Col1' % idx
    df[col1] = np.int32(0)
    df.loc[(df['name'].values == idx ) & (df['level'].values == 4), col1] = df.loc[(df['name'].values == idx ) & (df['level'].values == 4), 'xyz']
```

I´m doing this for 7 new columns per unique name. I researched a lot the last days and as I understood, python first creates a copy of my Data Frame, then it filters the Data Frame with my conditions and finally the filtered data are getting moved to the original Data Frame. The allocation for the copy of the Data Frame creates my Memory Error (I guess).

The question is: Is it possible to do the same thing inplace - without the Data Frame copy? 
I think that would fix my Memory Error.

Comment: Have you considered processing them in chunks?

Comment: I did. But I never tried because later, I gotta search in the whole DataFrame for IDs. Maybe I´ll try to split the Frame just for creating the new columns.

Comment: yes I would suggest so. that helps a lot to reduce memory usage. :)